# Install extensions for remote - ssh when remote machine is behind a proxy

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, proxy, vscode-remote

I've installed the Remote - SSH extension to develop while working from home, code that is sitting on a remote work computer. Previously I'd been using VSCode installed on the remote Linux machine and just used NX or some remote desktop software to connect and develop. I note that just to point out that a local version of VSCode is also installed on the machine. Now while home, I first connect my laptop to VPN and then using the Remote - SSH extension I am able to develop code sitting on the remote machine. For this SSH connection, I've installed a few extensions on the remote machine that seem to work fine, but I am having trouble installing or getting others to work. Namely the rust-analyzer extension won't install and the rust extension doesn't work. I assume it is because of the "Known limitations" listed on this page https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions where it advices to extensions may not work unless the appropriate environment variables are set. Previously I'd been setting http_proxy and https_proxy but now I also set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY because of this advice. However, setting these variables does not solve the problem. I also set these variables in .wgetrc following advice I found somewhere. If this is a proxy issue, how do I set the correct variable? Also, is there an alternative way to install extensions so that they work via the Remote - SSH extension?

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> "Remote" tab -> search "proxy"

set "Http: Proxy", and then reconnect remote